# Don't Change URL in Browser When Clicking <asp:LinkButton>

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have an ASP.NET page that uses a menu based on `asp:LinkButton` control in a Master page.  When a user selects a menu item, an `onclick` handler calls a method in my C# code.  The method it calls just does a `Server.Transfer()` to a new page.  From what I have read, this is not supposed to change the URL displayed in the browser.

The problem is it that the URL changes in the browser as the user navigates the menu to different pages.

Here is an item in the menu:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="foo" runat="server" onclick="changeToHelp"><span>Help</span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

In my C# code, I handle the event with a method like:

```
protected void changeToHelp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("Help.aspx");
}
```

Any ideas how I can navigate through the menu without the browser's URL bar changing?

Comment: I whipped up a sample application and it worked using your code right out of the gate. Is there anything else going on in the Page_Load event or any other Page event? Is the link contained in anything with an AutoPostBack or any sort of UpdatePanels?

Comment: Any chance you solved this issue? This question was auto bumped, so if you found the answer it's worth posting here for the sake of others. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use iframes to make sure that URL of browser doesn't change.
In Page_Load you can change src attribute of iframe to help.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try `Server.Execute("Help.aspx")` instead. You can preserve the form if you need by using

```
Server.Execute("Help.aspx",true);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.  My menu no longer switches pages when I change Server.Transfer() to Server.Execute()